# Abi to call value

Tags: contract-development, abi, state-variable

how to calculate ABI to call some variable in contract?

for example

```
 contract X {
   uint data;
   function Y(uint a) {}
}
```

How to calculate signature to call variable "data" ?
I know to call function we should do something like that keccak256("Y(uint)") but if we want to call variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All public variables generate a getter with the same name as the variable. So a variable with name `data` will result in a function with signature `function data()`.

Therefore, if you want, you can calculate the call signature with the formula you provided.

Answer (score 1):

`solc` will generate the ABI for you (as will remix and truffle)

Just run `solc --abi yourfile.sol`.

You can see a list of compiler options [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/using-the-compiler.html).